# How to get continuous output with Convolutional network in Keras?

Tags: regression, python, deep-learning, convolution

I'm a new user in using convolutional neural networks with keras. I have a code to classify set of images into 2 classes [0,1] using CNN in keras but I need to convert this code to get continuous output (linear regression,...) in keras. Could you explain this for me?

here is my code:

```
# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 187, 100


# preparing and import the dataset
path1 = '/home/fatmasaid/new_flicker'    #path of folder of images    
path2 = '/home/fatmasaid/new_flicker_data_resized'  #path of folder to save images    

listing = os.listdir(path1)
listing.sort(key=lambda f: int(filter(str.isdigit, f)))
num_samples=size(listing)

print (num_samples)
#exit()

for file in listing:
    im = Image.open(path1 + '//' + file)
    img = im.resize((img_rows,img_cols))
    gray = img.convert('L')
    gray.save(path2 +'//' +  file, "JPEG")

imlist = os.listdir(path2)
#sorting the list in ascending order by image name 
imlist.sort(key=lambda f: int(filter(str.isdigit, f))) 

im1 = array(Image.open('new_flicker_data_resized' + '//'+ imlist[0])) # open one image to get size et size
m,n = im1.shape[0:2] # get the size of the images
imnbr = len(imlist) # get the number of images

# create matrix to store all flattened images
immatrix = array([array(Image.open('new_flicker_data_resized'+ '//' + im2)).flatten()
              for im2 in imlist],'f')


#divide the dataset to 2 classes            
label=np.ones((num_samples,),dtype = int)

label[0:64878]=0     #images with low No of likes labeled 0
label[64878:]=1 #images with high No of likes labeled 1

data,Label = shuffle(immatrix,label, random_state=2)
train_data = [data,Label]

print (train_data[0].shape) # the train data
print (train_data[1].shape)  # the labels of these data

#batch_size to train
batch_size = 16
# number of output classes
nb_classes = 2
# number of epochs to train
nb_epoch =150 #each epochs contains around 70000/128=468 batches with 128 images

img_rows, img_cols = 187, 100

(X, Y) = (train_data[0],train_data[1])


# STEP 1: split X and y into training and testing sets

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=4)

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

#Normalization
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

# compute the total time of prearing and importing the dataset
t_generateArray = time.time()
print('Generating Array Time:{}'.format(t_generateArray - t_start))

print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_test, nb_classes)

# Step 1:Network structure
model = Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu',init='glorot_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))  # neuron number

# load weights
#model.load_weights("Train_Test_weights.h5")

#step 2: Learning target(computiong the loss using the entropy function
sgd = SGD(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
# adagrad = Adagrad(lr=0.01, epsilon=1e-08)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer= sgd,metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpointer=ModelCheckpoint(filepath='new_flicker_Train_Test_weights.h5',monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')

#training the model
print ('Training Start....')
hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
              verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),callbacks=[checkpointer])


#model.save_weights('Train_Test_weights.h5')

#evaluate the model
score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test,verbose=0)
print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

print(model.predict_classes(X_test[2:10]))
print(Y_test[2:10])


print ('drawing the training process...')
TrainERR = hist.history['loss']
ValidERR = hist.history['val_loss']
plt.figure(0)
plt.plot(TrainERR, 'b', label='TrainERR')
plt.plot(ValidERR, 'r', label='ValidERR')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.grid(True)
#plt.show()
plt.savefig('new_flicker_Train_Test_Loss&Epoch.png', dpi=150)

Trainer = hist.history['acc']
Valider = hist.history['val_acc']
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(Trainer, 'b', label='Trainer')
plt.plot(Valider, 'r', label='Valider')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.grid(True)
#plt.show()
plt.savefig('new_flicker_Train_Test_Accuracy&Epoch.png', dpi=150)

t_end = time.time()

print('Time:{}'.format(t_end - t_start))
print('Generating Array Time:{}'.format(t_generateArray - t_start))
```